# Eclipse always builds old code even if newer code exists

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I just started programming with c++ on Eclipse (Neon 3), but I already encountered a weird problem:

I wrote some simple code, tried to build it, encountered an error and changed something in the code. Now I wanted to rebuild it, but it still shows the same error and in the console, it only prints the old code. I tried to use clean, but that didn't help.

**My code:**

```c
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    string input;
    cout << " Bitte geben sie eine Buchstabenfolge ein. " << endl;
    getline(cin,input);
    //char first_letter = input[0];
    //cout << first_letter;
    return 0;
}
```

(I'm aware that this code is probably garbage, I'm just experimenting a bit)

**Console output:**

```
16:20:21 **** Incremental Build of configuration Debug for project ue3.2 ****
make all 
Building file: ../src/ue3.2.cpp
Invoking: GCC C++ Compiler
g++ -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"src/ue3.2.d" -MT"src/ue3.2.o" -o "src/ue3.2.o" "../src/ue3.2.cpp"
../src/ue3.2.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
../src/ue3.2.cpp:17:22: error: cannot convert ‘std::__cxx11::string {aka std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>}’ to ‘char’ in initialization
  char first_letter = input ;
                      ^
src/subdir.mk:18: recipe for target 'src/ue3.2.o' failed
make: *** [src/ue3.2.o] Error 1

16:20:21 Build Finished (took 129ms)
```

Comment: At least you should provide che code and the error message you get

Comment: It looks like the file is not being saved before the build is run? Can you confirm the file is indeed saved (according to Eclipse, no * in front of filename) and that if you open that file in another editor the contents are there? If the contents are there, then g++ is not compiling the file you think it is, so check the paths.

Answer (score 0):

*(Posted on behalf of the OP)*.

For some reason the problem is gone now. Before anything else, I checked for updates with the installer and it downloaded some. After that, I started Eclipse and everything seemed to be fine. Additionally, I noticed that I gave the project a stupid name (there was a "." in it) and changed it. Issue is apparently gone, although I don't really know how and why.